# SaveLayoutToStream. Error: Could not find part of the path "c: \ TreeListLayout \"

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I try to run an example - [link](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraTreeList.TreeList.SaveLayoutToStream.method(S1oTsg))
User - admin
Scenario:
  - I expand the treelist node;
  - I execute the "SaveLayoutToStream_mtd ()" method;

I get in line

```
System.IO.FileStream outFile = new System.IO.FileStream(fileName, System.IO.FileMode.Create);
```

an error

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: "Could not find part of the
>   path" c: \ TreeListLayout \ "."

all code

```
string fileName = @"c:\TreeListLayout\";
public void SaveLayoutToStream_mtd()
{            
    System.IO.FileStream outFile = new System.IO.FileStream(fileName, System.IO.FileMode.Create);
    treeList1.SaveLayoutToStream(outFile);
    outFile.Close();
}
```

How to fix the error?

Comment: removed the last slash from your file name,  `string fileName = @"c:\TreeListLayout";`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you seen the difference between your code and the example you've referenced? You are trying to write to a file with the invalid name `c:\TreeListLayout\` - that is a directory name.  Either remove the trailing slash or append a file name

Comment: Removed the slash.
Now string fileName = @ "c: \ TreeListLayout";
Mistake.
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: "Access is denied on the path" c: \ TreeListLayout "."

Comment: So? Obviously, the program you are running has no permission to use that path. Either use a path where this is no problem (like not in the root area or in the program section) or run your program with root permissions if the given file location must be held

Comment: I created a folder
"bin \ Debug \ TreeListLayout \"
string fileName = @ ".. \ TreeListLayout";

There are no errors.
But nothing happens in the folder.
After executing the method, the folder is empty.
Or should it be?

Comment: Why does your file name contain spaces? Are you sure that writing is supposed to work with a relative path?

Comment: 1. Problems were formed in the process of copying. There are no spaces in the code.
2. If I prescribe the full path, then I get an error `Access denied on the way`

3. It is strange that problems with the path.
I have a database in the folder "z: \ vs \ csharp \ prb \ 513 \ 01_pr \ rsh \". And there are no problems. Data is written / read to the database without problems.